# Можно ли в Telegram Bot Api получить обратно текст отправленного ботом сообщения?

Tags: telegram-bot

Случай: бот отправляет некое произвольное сообщение. Через какое-то время нужно это сообщение отредактировать, но бот не помнит его текст. Хотя id чата и id сообщения известны. Возможно ли как-то получить обратно его текст? Метод getUpdates, на сколько я понял, позволяет это сделать только с сообщениями от пользователей, свои собственные сообщения он не показывает.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. Редактирование сообщений бота реализуется методом [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext):

> Use this method to edit text and game messages sent by the bot or via the bot (for inline bots). On success, if edited message is sent by the bot, the edited Message is returned, otherwise True is returned.

В целом о редактировании сообщений бота из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages):

> **Updating messages**
>
> The following methods allow you to change an existing message in the
>   message history instead of sending a new one with a result of an
>   action. This is most useful for messages with inline keyboards using
>   callback queries, but can also help reduce clutter in conversations
>   with regular chat bots.
>
> Please note, that it is currently only possible to edit messages
>   without reply_markup or with inline keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, просто так по запросу получить текст произвольного сообщения по *chat_id* и *message_id* **не получится**. Поэтому нужно либо запоминать текст отправленных сообщений, либо конструировать его заново.

Однако если редактировать сообщение нужно по опредённым событиям, то, возможно, метод `getUpdates` будет полезным — он возвращает содержимое всех релевантных сообщений. Например, при нажатии на inline кнопку бот получает текст сообщения с этой кнопкой, при ответе, бот видит сообщение, на которое ответили и т.п.